# Eclipse C99 struct initialization formatting

Tags: c, eclipse, formatting, initialization

Does anyone know how I can set the code formatting in Eclipse for c99-style struct initialization lists?

At the moment the code formatting makes any struct initialization list look like that:

```
Test test =
{ .a= 0, .b= 0, .c = 0};
```

I want it to look like that, so that every member is in a new line:

```
Test test=
{
        .a = 0,
        .b = 0,
        .c = 0
};
```

I could not find any setting which changes the look of the initialization. It does not have to seem anything to do with array initialization lists

Comment: It has nothing to do with [tag:c] but its a feature of eclipse.

Comment: @TonyTannous It has, of course, everything to do with C code formatting in Eclipse. I don't expect non-C programmers to be able to answer the question. So the question was correctly tagged, I'll rollback the edit.

Comment: @Lundin Okay, I get what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

It will be called something like Project -> Properties -> C/C++ general -> Formatter. Check "enable project specific settings" where you can create your own style rules. Create a new style profile or edit an existing one.

- Under the tab ***Line Wrapping*** there is an option ***Initializer list*** which should apply to traditional initializer lists as well as C99 designated initializers.
- Under the tab ***Braces*** there is another option ***Initializer list*** which you like to set to *Next line indented*.

Comment: I already changed the "line wrapping" --> "initializer list" --> "line wrapping policy" to "wrap all elements, every element on a new line". But does only appear to affect standart arrays

Comment: @oliverleo Ah really? Well then I guess this answer isn't helpful. In which case I'll resort to my standard advice: uninstall Eclipse ASAP and avoid it like the plague in the future.

Comment: If the answer is not helpful perhaps better to delete.

Comment: Indeed, I will leave it around until a solution is provided however, in case someone else is tempted to post the same answer (as it should be correct in theory... but broken in reality, as is the norm in Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

I came around the same question and the first suggestion of @howlger worked for me. However, the braces are still not placed as intended:

```
  busDriverData->status = (BusDriverStatusType )
  {
      .localWakeup = false,
      .remoteWakeup = false,
      .nodeConfig = false,
      .pwon = false,
      .busError = false,
      .tempHigh = false,
      .tempMedium = false,
      .txenBGEClamped = false,
      .uvvbat = false,
      .uvvcc = false,
      .uvvio = false,
      .starLocked = false,
      .trxdCollision = false };
```

Here is my XML style file: [Click](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=26127856786701177628)